# Inference in Dirichlet process mixtures via collapsed Gibbs sampling

Tags: self-study, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, markov-chain-montecarlo, graphical-model

I need to cluster some data $\{x1, \ldots, x_n\}$ through a Dirichlet process mixture model.
Consider the following Dirichlet process mixture model, in which the base measure is a $NIW(\mu_0, \lambda_0, \nu_0, S)$ distribution and the random probability measure $G = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \pi_k \delta_{(\mu_k, \Sigma_k)}$ is constructed according to stick breaking:

$$\pi \sim GEM(\alpha)$$
$$ \{\mu_k, \Sigma_k\} \sim NIW(\mu_0, \lambda_0, \nu_0, S) $$
$$ z_i | \pi \sim \pi$$
$$x_i | Z_i, \{\mu_k, \Sigma_k\} \sim N(\mu_{z_i}, \Sigma_{z_i})$$

I need to design a collapsed Gibbs sampler. Also, I need to a posteriori estimate $\{\mu_k, \Sigma_k\}$ for all clusters in the data.
It is clear that this requires integrating out $\pi$ and $ \{\mu_k, \Sigma_k\}$, thus leading to sample only the $z_i$'s. However, it is not clear to me how to formally obtain the $\{\mu_k, \Sigma_k\}$ subsequently to the collapsed Gibbs sampling process. What about the $\pi_k$'s subsequently to the collapsed Gibbs sampling process?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in bayesian non-parametrics but I think I can help a little. Others please correct me If i am wrong.

Based on your model, you would have $\boldsymbol{\pi}, \mu, \Sigma, \boldsymbol{Z}$  as your latent variables and $\boldsymbol{X}$ as your observables. I use bold symbols to represent vectors. The objective is to find the posterior distribution $p(\boldsymbol{\pi}, \boldsymbol{Z}, \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}|\boldsymbol{X})$. Based on the Gibbs sampling procedure, you would have to sample for each latent variable
$$\pi_i \sim p(\pi_i|\boldsymbol{\pi_{-i}}, \boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma},\ \boldsymbol{Z},\boldsymbol{X}) \\
(\mu_k, \Sigma_k) \sim p(\mu_k, \Sigma_k|\boldsymbol{\mu_{-k}},\boldsymbol{\Sigma_{-k}}, \boldsymbol{\pi},  \boldsymbol{Z}, \boldsymbol{X})\\
z_i \sim p(z_i | \boldsymbol{Z}_{-i}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}, \boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\pi}, \boldsymbol{X})  
$$
where the $-i$, $-k$ subscript denotes the latent variables excluding the $i$-th and $k$-th variable for that vector.
Sampling $\pi_i$ is difficult because the Dirichlet Process defines an infinite number of clusters a priori. However, we don't actually need to know the mixture weights $\pi_i$ because we are interested in the cluster assignments and the parameters that define each cluster. Hence, we can do a collapsed gibbs sampling procedure by integrating out $\pi$ from the complete conditionals. Therefore, we now sample
$$
(\mu_k, \Sigma_k) \sim p(\mu_k, \Sigma_k|\boldsymbol{\mu_{-k}}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma_{-k}}, \boldsymbol{Z}, \boldsymbol{X})\\
z_i \sim p(z_i|\boldsymbol{Z}_{-i}, \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}, \boldsymbol{X})
$$

To sample from these conditional distributions, refer to [Radford Neal's paper](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/npbayes/papers/neal_sampling.pdf) for a more detailed explanation on how to sample from dirichlet process mixture models.

- You can either use Gibbs sampling (if you are using Conjugate priors)
  or Metropolis Hastings to sample from these conditional posteriors.

### Gibbs Sampling for DPMM

Suppose that you are using conjugate priors, then when you sample $z_i$ there are two outcomes.
The first outcome is that you sample a $z_i = z$ where $z$ is already an existing cluster, the probability of this happening is given by the equation
$$
P(z_i = z|\boldsymbol{z}_{-i}, x_i, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}, \boldsymbol{\mu}) = b\frac{n_{-i,z}}{n - 1 + \alpha}F(x_i, (\mu_z, \Sigma_z))
$$
where $b$ is the normalizing constant that makes the conditional distributions sum to 1, $n_{-i,z}$ represents the number of points belonging to cluster $z$ excluding the $i$-th point $z_i$, and $F(x_i, (\mu_z,\Sigma_z))$ represents the likelihood of the point $x_i$ under the NIW distribution with parameters $\mu_z, \Sigma_z$.

The second outcome is when you sample a $z_i = z$ that is not part of an existing cluster, meaning that the point $x_i$ belongs to a new cluster.
The probability of sampling a new cluster is given by the equation
$$P(z_i = z|\boldsymbol{z}_{-i}, x_i, \boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}) = b\frac{\alpha}{n - 1 + \alpha}\int F(x_i, \mu, \Sigma)dG_0(\mu, \Sigma)
$$
$\int F(x_i, \mu, \Sigma)dG_0(\mu, \sigma)$ is just the prior predictive distribution of the data point $x_i$. This integral can be computed exactly because of conjugacy in the likelihood and prior.

With these equations, you can form a complete probability distribution to sample the $z_i$'s.

To sample $(\mu_k, \Sigma_k)$, you need to sample from the posterior distribution of $\mu_k, \Sigma_k$ conditioned on all the data points belonging to cluster $k$.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions and please correct me if I am wrong in some points.

Comment: I thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I still need to see the explicit derivation in the concrete case of my example.

Comment: U can have a look at radford neal's paper for a more detailed derivation of how to integrate out the $\pi$'s, or have a look at this tutorial on DPMM; https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6583910/  Radford neal's paper should also include an algorithm to that integrates out both $\pi$, $\mu_k, \Sigma_k$.